# How to style Select2 input tags with css and how to limit them

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

I am very new to making web pages and to this website.

I managed to make a system to add tags; however, I have no idea how to style it. I tried doing:

```
input[type=text] { border-radius:5px;}
```

But this does not work. Here is my entire code:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="select2/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('#select').select2({
          // specify tags
          tags: ["Value 1", "Value2"],
          maximumSelectionSize: 3
        });
      });
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="select2/select2.css">
    <style>
        border-radius:20px;
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="select" style="width:300px" placeholder="Select Categories">
  </body>

</html>
```

That is my first problem.

My second problem is that `maximumSelectionSize: 3` does not work well: if you write three tags, it reminds you of the limit and doesn't allow more. However when you delete them and try to enter new ones, it still shows that you have written 3 tags.

(I apologize if these questions has been repeated before.. I tried searching for them but I couldn't find anything.)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: For the moment, I can answer one of your two questions. In order to try and change the css, 'input[type=text]' won't work, because select2 will hide any select element and generate a custom element based on the former. In this way, each custom element has this class: 'select2-choice'. So ovewrite the style by using this class.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/564e2x0h/3/ is this helps you?

Comment: Kheema, the external resources for that helped.. I used those instead of the ones saved on my computer and now my second issue is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to alter the select2.css style to increase the border radius

Amend the following style selector with your desired border-radius: 
**.select2-container-multi .select2-choice {border-radius:20px;}**

For the second issue, alter your select2 function to match the following and change the input element to a div element in your html and delete the "placeholder" attribute from the tag. Here is the code sample:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#select').select2({
            tags: ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5"],
            placeholder: "Select Categories",
            maximumSelectionSize: 3
     });
    });
</script>

<div id="select" style="width:300px"></div>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for such a quick reply. I found out that the second issue doesn't work on localhost but it works on jfiddle. It works regardless of <div> or <input> tags. I found out that this was because I was using the wrong external resources (select2.js). Thank you for specifically telling me how to fix the border-radius.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tanay_Singhal/dth1xaL4/1/

EDIT:
Styling worked with
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices {

(just needed to add that small s but I figured it out haha) :)

Comment: No problem Drago, was doing this one a 3am after finishing some other stuff, so I am not surprised that I didn't get it exactly right. Glad I could help steer you in the right direction though. Enjoy!